# how to check date object is today in Android

Tags: android, date

I have a date object like the following code .

```
long millis = smsInboxCursor.getLong(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            String smsDate = (String) DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss ", new Date(millis));
```

I want to check whether  smsDate is today or another day . If  smsDate is today then I want to retrieve only the time . If  smsDate is another day < I want to retrieve only the date and month . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Date Object, truncate it to date only and compare it with the one you already have. If the date is the same, use the class SimpleDateFormat to grab just the time and use that.

Edit:

to compare a Date Object with the actual Date you can do it like this:

```
//Format to compare, you want to check the Date only i guess?       

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

Date dateSms = new Date(millis);
Date dateToday = new Date();

String smsDateYYYYMMDD = sdf.format(dateSms); 
String dateYYYYMMDD = sdf.format(dateToday);
```

You can now compare this two Strings or you go instead with 
"Date checkDate = sdf.parse(DateString)" to compare Date Objects

play arround with that a little bit and you get used to it quick

Answer (score 2):

```
long millis = smsInboxCursor.getLong(smsInboxCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
            Date date = new Date(millis);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            // set the calendar to start of today
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            // and get that as a Date
            Date today = c.getTime();
            String smsDate;
            if (date.before(today)) { 
                smsDate = (String) DateFormat.format(
                        " MMMM dd ", new Date(millis));
            } else { 
                smsDate = (String) DateFormat.format(
                        "  h:mm ", new Date(millis));
            }
```